# Why is this simple array sorting method in Java not behaving normally when changing initializing?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, initialization, logic

I looked up this array sorting method and there's one thing that confuses me about it when changing the initial for-loop initialization.

The original for-loop was initialized by 1

> (1)        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)

I then decided to initialize it by 0 so I adjusted list.length in the if-statement accordingly by deducting 1.

> (2)        for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)

Here's the full sorting method:-

```
public static void sortList(int[] list) {

    int temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (list[j] < list[j - 1]) {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j - 1];
                list[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The original four loop mentioned in the code above correctly sorts the following array [5, 3, 10, 8] to [3, 5, 8, 10]

But my adjustment results in the following: [3, 5, 10, 8].

Why does the original four-loop work, but mine doesn't? Shouldn't both four-loops run 3 times?

I later fixed my issue by adding an equal to the lesser-than operator

> (3)    for (int i = 0; i <= list.length-1; i++)

But I don't get *why* it works now. This new four-loop now runs 4 times contrary to how it runs 3 times in the original one and both managed to sort the array.

My question is simple, and its answer is almost certainly a simple one too but I'm too much of a novice to figure it out myself.

Why do these two work:-

> (1) for (int i = 0; i <= list.length-1; i++)
>
> (2) for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)

But not this one:-

> (3) for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)

Even though four-loop (1) and (3) are identical.

Comment: It's not a matter of "runs 4 times", but what elements it's looking at.   When you made your first change, by reducing the end-position you stopped the algorithm from looking at the last element.   By introducing the "<=", it was able to look at the last element again.

Comment: @sprinter No, there is a `j > 0` condition in that `for`

Answer (score 0):

Because `(2) for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)` simply ignores the `list.length-1` element of the input array. It is never processed, so it will always stay on the  last position in the initial array.

Loops (1) and (3) are not identical since `(1) for (int i = 0; i <= list.length-1; i++)` will process the last element.